# WordPress eCommerce Plugin: "Products" Shown on Page 2

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

The WordPress eCommerce Plugin is showing products beginning on page two instead of the first page.

This happened after I moved the template CSS file from WP eCommerce plugin. How can I move back the CSS file from theme directory?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to make sure that others have the best chance of being able to help you, please try to add as much detail to your question as possible. For example, explaining where you moved the "template CSS file" might make it easier for someone to help you to revert that change.

Comment: To elaborate on what @nmagerko said - please add some info as to your file structure (before & after), relevant code, etc. Anything you'd show a friend who came to your desk and wanted to know what the issue is